# Intrinsic safety connection protection between two intrinsic safety devices inside a hazardous zone

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, circuit-protection, hardware, iec

[image]

I am designing an RF module in in a hazardous zone (in the picture it is shown with DCDC and MCU etc.) My module gets power supply from AC/DC.

I read about intrinsic safety barriers from the IEC 60079-11 and also a lot of articles and one thing is unclear for me. This is my first project around such safety conditions. Maybe you can help me?

All of these sources of information describe situations when external power is taken from unhazardous zone and intrinsic safety barriers are required for the devices which are powered supply side and this barrier must be placed on the output of power supply. How should I protect the power input of my device if it takes power supply from the cable in hazardous zone from safety AC/DC?

Comment: I've designed a number of IS products, and my first step is to engage UL for consulting.  One guy I interacted with told me that the interpretation of IS requirements mutates so rapidly that if he left UL, his skills would be obsolete in months.  It's an extremely complicated field, more legal than technical in many ways.  If you're going to do an IS project from scratch without a consultant, prepare for numerous redesigns when you start submitting it for certification.

Comment: The mains connection to the power supply is not intrinsically safe, therefore the power supply needs to be enclosed in an ExD rated enclosure in the hazardous area. The output of the power supply may be intrinsically safe so the wiring for that needs to have a minimum separation from non intrinsically safe circuits. The power supply should come with explicit instructions regarding this. Intrinsic safety is about ensuring there is not enough energy available to cause a spark. Inductance and capacitance are critical parameters, so your wiring and other circuits need to be below certain values.